# Customizable centered box grid in html/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

This is what my site currently looks like:

[image]

I am trying to make the boxes a fixed square width and want them to be always centered horizontally and vertically. either like

[] [] [] []

or

[] []

[] []

currently they slope to the side:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFJdQ.png)

Is there a way to make this work without javascript?

current html:

```
            <div class="grid-item">
                <a href="https://download.tails.net/tails/stable/tails-amd64-6.0/tails-amd64-6.0.img">
                    <img class="app-image" src="assets/tails.png" height="100px">
                    <div class="app-title">Tails 6</div>
                    <div class="app-description">Amnesic live system.</div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

current css:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  margin: 0;
}

.body-default {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center ;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.grid-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 2px solid #4e4e4e;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  background-color: #242424;
  transition: transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0,.75,.25,1);
  transform-origin: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

.app-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.app-description {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: #808080;
}

.app-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.centered-box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This code fixes formatting:

```
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}


.grid-item {
  border: 2px solid #4e4e4e;
  width: 200px;
  height: 210px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  background-color: #242424;
  transition: transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0,.75,.25,1);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp7DU.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).